# Rails jquery-fileupload gem - couldn't find file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to follow the Railscasts episode on jQuery-FileUpload. I've added

```
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
```

to the assets group of the `Gemfile`, and also added the

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

line to the `application.js` file in the asset directory. When I try to bring up the website, however, the following error is shown:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-fileupload'
  (in root/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing first whitespace at this line at application.js: `//=require jquery-fileupload/basic`

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: Have you run `bundle update` after adding plugin to `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yep. Ran `bundle install` to make sure it was installed.

Comment: Probably, in `application.js`, there are some whitespaces between Sprockets expressions began with `//=`, could you check it, too?

Comment: I tried searching for any whitespaces using ctrl+f in my texteditor but I can't seem to find any between Sprockets expressions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25395/discussion-between-ekremkrc-and-jkface)

Comment: I found a "solution" - restarting rails server did the trick. I can't believe I didn't think of doing that earlier. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @jeebface Please place this in an answer and accept your answer. It seems obvious but I made the same mistake. I read every answer and thought this question was unhelpful. I didn't realize you had solved it. Thanks for the solution though. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a "solution" - restarting rails server did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Remove it from assets group, and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have fix this by :

add

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

to your Gemfile.

and run `bundle install`
and
`rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird, I just tried with a `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and on application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

and worked great, did you run bundle ? I know its a stupid question but it may be

Comment: I even updated my rails gem from 3.2.11 to 3.2.12 but it's still not working. I'm not really sure what to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, if you are able to push your app on github I could try to find the issue, it just doesn't make sense that your asset can not be found. Could you put your complete Gemfile just in case?

Comment: I found a "solution" - restarting rails server did the trick. I can't believe I didn't think of doing that. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna add the following line to application.js

```
//= require jquery-fileupload
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar lately. What worked for me was to load the gem directly from git

```
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails', git: 'git://github.com/ollnixon/jquery-fileupload-rails.git'
```

And then to load the the needed ui styles

```
*= require jquery.fileupload-ui
```

Works flawlessly now