# Trying to include and use jquery file upload on rails throwing some errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-file-upload, sprockets

I am trying to build an app with rails,
and in some module, I need to use custom file uploader,
I try to use jquery file upload, but somehow it throws me an error?

Here is what I have tried:

I added below codes to my gem file :

```
group :assets do
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'jquery.fileupload-rails'
end
```

**Note** : I also tried to put my jquery file upload rails gem outside the asset group.

Added this to application js :

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

When I try to access my view, I got this error

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-fileupload/basic' with type 'application/javascript'
```

oh FYI : I use rails 4.2.7
and windows 7 64 bits.

Forgot to mention I have run bundle install command too.

apt model

```
class Apt < ActiveRecord::Base




  belongs_to :developer
  belongs_to :area

  has_many :floorplans
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :floorplans




  validates :apt_name, presence: true
  validates :apt_address, presence: true
  validates :apt_desc, presence: true





end
```

floorplan model

```
class Floorplan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :apt

  mount_uploader :floorplanphoto, DefaultFileUploader
end
```

here is the request i did :

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mDfWGOI+lVOrOBmi038/oRFRoM5NUdkOL4caWPp30U/pLD41X5kpIur8Mdyqau5vE58C74BzXY7fvGfZn3dgLA==",
 "apt"=>{"apt_name"=>"twss",
 "apt_address"=>"xccxcxcx",
 "apt_lat"=>"",
 "apt_long"=>"",
 "thumbnail"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xaa3d018 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160811-9036-10xugyq.jpg>,
 @original_filename="Hydrangeas.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apt[thumbnail]\"; filename=\"Hydrangeas.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "apt_desc"=>"xcxccxcx",
 "developer_id"=>"3",
 "area_id"=>"1",
 "apt_status"=>"draft",
 "facility_ids"=>["1",
 ""],
 "poi_ids"=>["1",
 ""]},
 "floorplans"=>{"floorplanphoto"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xaa3cce8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160811-9036-9d1kdg.jpg>,
 @original_filename="Penguins.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"floorplans[floorplanphoto][]\"; filename=\"Penguins.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}}
```

as u can see there, i have floorplans inside my parameters, but it throw undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` error

i tried to print my parameters on console and it did not have floorplans?

```
>>  apt_params
=> {"apt_name"=>"twss", "apt_address"=>"xccxcxcx", "apt_lat"=>"", "apt_long"=>"", "thumbnail"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xaa3d018 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160811-9036-10xugyq.jpg>, @original_filename="Hydrangeas.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apt[thumbnail]\"; filename=\"Hydrangeas.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "apt_desc"=>"xcxccxcx", "developer_id"=>"3", "area_id"=>"1", "apt_status"=>"draft", "facility_ids"=>["1", ""], "poi_ids"=>["1", ""]}
```

Comment: just want to confirm, did you run bundle install after adding gem?

Comment: i did. forgot to mention that

Comment: try restart rails server.

Comment: i already did that, still no luck.

Comment: there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168943/rails-jquery-fileupload-gem-couldnt-find-file-error which having multiple solutions you can try them.

Comment: i've tried all, still no luck... thx for suggestion anyway.

Comment: You can use [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) gem.

Comment: @SpunkyLive do you have any reference or example about the usage of that gem? thx before.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Instead of using gem download the script and keep it in app/assets/javascripts folder. Suppose your script is inside folder jquery-fileupload and you need to load basic.js.

Now in application.js file in app/assets/javascript folder just add line `//= require jquery-fileupload/basic`. And restart your server.

This must solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use remotipart gem

In Gemfile

```
gem 'remotipart'
```

In application.js

```
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require_tree .
```

form

```
<%= form_for @apt, multipart: true, remote: true do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field :apt_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :apt_address %>
  <%= f.text_field :apt_desc %>
  <%= f.fields_for :floorplans do |p| %>
     <%= p.file_field :floorplanphoto, :multiple => true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/apts_controller.js

```
def create 
  @apt = Apt.new(apt_params)
  format_to do |format|
     if @apt.save
       apt_params[:floorplans].each do |a|
         @floor_plans = @apt.floorplans.create!(a)
       end
       format.js {:locals => {:request => true}}
     else
       format.js {:locals => {:request => false}}
     end 
  end   
end

private

def apt_params
  params.require(:apt).permit(:apt_name, :apt_address, apt_desc, floorplans: [:id, :post_id, :floorplanphoto])
end
```

views/users/create.js.erb

```
<% if remotipart_submitted? %>
  if(<%= request %>) 
    // image is uploaded
  else
    // you can show here custom error msg
<% else %>
    // Error in xhr request
<% end %>
```

There will be no changes in Model.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: how does the model looks like? is this gem support multiple upload?

Comment: Please share your model

Comment: i have edited my post with models, basically an apt may have more than 1 floor plans, so it has one to many relationship.

Comment: somehow it did not work, my floorplans always {0}, i guess it has somethign to do with strong parameters.

Comment: Updated the answer. and also can you share your params what you are getting.

Comment: You are getting everything, so what is the problem.

Comment: Remove  `name: "floorplans[floorplanphoto][]" ` from `<%= p.file_field :floorplanphoto, :multiple => true, name: "floorplans[floorplanphoto][]" %>`